# @Url.action cast exception

Tags: c#-4.0, url.action

I am trying to implement @Url.Action on a link to be clicked.

```
 link = "@Url.Action("ExportWeeklyTimesheetPDF", "Hours", new { projectId = Model.ProjectId, reportType = 'Week', reportDate = 'reportDate'})"
 link.replace("reportDate",dateString);
 $("#exportPDF").attr("href", link);
```

When I try to add  , reportType = 'Week', reportDate = 'reportDate'   I keep getting unhandled cast exception. If I dont have the reportType and reportDate, its working fine. How to solve this mess? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you
Nikhil

Comment: What's in `dateString`? Can you give us an example?

Comment: Also, shouldn't `Week` and `reportDate` be double quoted as they are `string`s not `char`s.

Comment: Me new to asp.net
I am not sure if what i've written is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're trying to assign the return value of the C# method to a javascript variable, then replace part of it with another javascript variable. Correct me if I'm wrong.

You need to take a closer look and work out what you've written is doing. It won't work because you're using single quotes instead of double, and the javascript `link.replace` line will only replace the first instance of `reportDate`.

This code should work:

```
@{
  string url = Url.Action("ExportWeeklyTimesheetPDF", "Hours", new { projectId = Model.ProjectId, reportType = "Week", reportDate = "replaceWithReportDate"});
}

link = "@url";
link.replace("replaceWithReportDate", dateString);
$("#exportPDF").attr("href", link);
```

You'll still need to ensure that the `replaceWithReportDate` is changed in the resulting link to be in the expected format.